# Has anyone successfully used selenium-ide to enter data into google docs? If not is there another option?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I am trying to use selenium to enter data into google docs so that it is accessible to other selenium scripts. If not can anybody think of a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium can be a little flaky with contentEditable areas because the way that Selenium "types" onto the page and how browsers really interact with that.

I would recommend inserting the text into the element with JavaScript and then doing the manipulations.

If you want a truer sense then I would recommend moving to Selenium 2 as the keystrokes are more OS native. This unfortunately does not work in the IDE and you will have to use Python, Java, .NET or Ruby to take advantage of it.